# How do I merge rows of data with the same ID but different data in other columns and remove duplicate contiunous words?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, nlp, stanford-nlp

I have a set of data in a pandas dataframe

| ID | Date | Location | Text |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123456 | 01/01/23 | Paris | Reported Problem: |
| 123456 | 01/01/23 | Paris | Reported Problem: One Plus One Is Not Three |
| 123456 | 01/01/23 | Paris | Reported Problem: One Plus One Is Not Three |
| 123456 | 01/01/23 | Paris | Reported Pro |
| 123456 | 01/01/23 | Paris | Reported Problem: One Plus One Is Not Three. Potato Grows On Tree |

I want to merge them all together so that they are only one row, and the text to merge together and delete the duplicate text. The desired result is

| ID | Date | Location | Text |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123456 | 01/01/23 | Paris | Reported Problem:\nReported Problem: One Plus One Is Not Three. Potato Grows On Tree |

I used groupby to merge the rows together, but there are duplicate that needs to be remove

| ID | Date | Location | Text |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123456 | 01/01/23 | Paris | Reported Problem:\nReported Problem: One Plus One Is Not Three\nReported Problem: One Plus One Is Not Three\nReported Pro\nReported Problem: One Plus One Is Not Three. Potato Grows On Tree |

I tried converting the merged data to a list and tokenize and segment the sentences using Stanza, using the newline to separate the sentences

But I'm not sure where to go from here
I'm using Stanza to split the sentences that way I can hopefully get sentences I need and put it into a PowerPoint with Python-pptx

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('Samplepool.csv')

g = df['ID'].ffill()

d = df.groupby(g, sort=False).first()

d['Text'] = df['Text'].dropna().groupby(g).agg('!'.join)
d = d.reset_index(drop=True)
```

```
import stanza
#stanza.download('en') # download English model
npl = stanza.Pipeline(lang='en', processors={'tokenize': 'TokenizeProcessor',},tokenize_no_ssplit=True)

sample2=d['Text'].to_list()
doc = npl(sample2)
#word = ['Report Problem']
for i, sentence in enumerate(doc.sentences):
    print(f'====== Sentence {i+1} tokens =======')
    print(*[token.text for token in sentence.tokens], sep='\n')
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a starting point. You can group by your desired level of aggregation (e.g. ID, date and location) and then produce a set of the strings. Sets, by their definition, will remove any duplicated values. From there, you can process further.

```
x = [
[123456, '01/01/23', 'Paris', 'Reported Problem:'],
[123456, '01/01/23', 'Paris', 'Reported Problem: One Plus One Is Not Three'],
[123456, '01/01/23', 'Paris', 'Reported Problem: One Plus One Is Not Three'],
[123456, '01/01/23', 'Paris', 'Reported Pro'],
[123456, '01/01/23', 'Paris', 'Reported Problem: One Plus One Is Not Three. Potato Grows On Tree']]

df = pd.DataFrame(x, columns=['id', 'date', 'location', 'text'])

df = (df
      .groupby(['id', 'date', 'location'])['text']
      .apply(set)
      .to_frame()
      .reset_index())

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    set_of_strings = row['text']
    print(type(set_of_strings))
    
    for i, string in enumerate(set_of_strings):
        print(i, string)
```

Output which is free of duplicates:

```
<class 'set'>
0 Reported Problem: One Plus One Is Not Three. Potato Grows On Tree
1 Reported Problem:
2 Reported Problem: One Plus One Is Not Three
3 Reported Pro
```

It isn't explicit in your question but it looks like you're trying to take everything after the `Reported Problem:` substring. You can do this as a first step using something like this:

```
df['text'] = df['text'].str.split('Reported Problem:').str[1]
```